# Bootstrap not working - where's the error?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Could somebody please show me an error in this code? I checked the file structure over and over and it seems ok, anyway, in the Network tab I only get a warning "Provisional headers are shown" but it seems like the files are fetched.

What happens is that although I made 3 collumns, I can see them one under another, full width of the container. The button css seems to be working though.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
                fdsf fds lkj ah soij saklmds a;sldj nas.d iashd aslkdm aosifh saf safd fdsf fds lkj ah soij saklmds a;sldj nas.d iashd aslkdm aosifh saf safd fdsf fds lkj ah soij saklmds a;sldj nas.d iashd aslkdm aosifh saf safd
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
                fdsf fds lkj ah soij saklmds a;sldj nas.d iashd aslkdm aosifh saf safd fdsf fds lkj ah soij saklmds a;sldj nas.d iashd aslkdm aosifh saf safd fdsf fds lkj ah soij saklmds a;sldj nas.d iashd aslkdm aosifh saf safd
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
                fdsf fds lkj ah soij saklmds a;sldj nas.d iashd aslkdm aosifh saf safd fdsf fds lkj ah soij saklmds a;sldj nas.d iashd aslkdm aosifh saf safd fdsf fds lkj ah soij saklmds a;sldj nas.d iashd aslkdm aosifh saf safd
    </div>
    <button class='btn btn-default'>fdsfds</button>
</div>
</div>

  <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have your tried to add slash on every src attribute? src="/js..." etc. Also see the console, and try this: $(document).ready(function(){alert('jquery is loaded')});

Comment: I've tried slashes, dot-slash, doubledot-slash without success. The alert shows up, so I really don't know.

Comment: Are you testing in a small screen? Though I highly doubt that :/

Comment: Try right-clicking the column and "Inspect Element", see if you can see if there is a "width" applied to CSS.

Comment: I've done that, I can see some bootstrap styles for the body, div has display: block, but no width applied.

Comment: What browser[s] (and version[s]) are you testing in? Are you testing on your local filesystem or on a server? What version of Bootstrap are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm , I also cannot find any errors in your code, 
are the bootraps files (bootstrap.js, css ..) are ok ??
I would try to download the newest Bootsraps and try it again.

Comment: I've just downloaded the brand new Bootstrap, cleared the cache, checked the console for errors... nothing.

Comment: Aaa I cannot believe it. Somehow the "brand new Bootstrap" that I've downloaded was not 3.0 so it had no styles for collumns (only for span). I accept your answer as correct, thnx!

Answer (score 1):

What you should see:

[image: What you should see]

### Your code:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

### Fix:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

You didn't declare to the browser that the `.css` is indeed a stylesheet (for older browsers). Also, you don't need to use `media="screen"`. In the new HTML5, you can drop `type="text/css"` too, but I would keep it there just to be safe this year(2014).

Comment: Unfortunately still the same... btw, you have a typo, "bootstYrap".

Comment: Did you try "Inspect Element"?

Comment: Vote up for you as after inspecting the element I started wondering why is there style for everything else but columns. See my comment under accepted answer, thnx!

Answer (score 0):

Tried putting your button in one of columns? sor exampel col-md-12?

Try this:

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"><p>Box 1</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"><p>Box 2</p></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"><p>Box 3</p></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

You could check it here:
http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=grid-layout-for-medium-devices

Comment: Having 2 classes like that is redundant, since `col-md-4` is inside the area of effect as `col-sm-4`

Comment: Agree, thanks for mentioning. col-sm-4 will work, because sm has width property set to 33.3%, and that works:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the bootstrap.min.js file not the bootstrap.js!

For example:

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Also, check that that your folders acutally contain the files.

Read here:
http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Kind Regards,
Josh

Comment: I've used bootstrap.min.js, as it wasn't working I tried with bootstrap.js... the folders contain the files.

Comment: Look at this site: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/ have you included the files in the way stated on the example there? I.E using the jquery file from ajax.google?

Comment: Sorry, scroll down to 'Basic Template'.

Comment: I've made a copy-paste from that code now and still nothing. Weirdest thing ever.

Comment: What width is your screen that your testing on?

Comment: Also, what browser are you using?

Comment: It's 1920 x 1080, and I've tried Chrome and Opera. I also added col-sm-4 and col-lg-4 just in case, no success!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62242/discussion-between-josh90-and-oneday).